# How to open an Image on a Mac

Tags: objective-c, image, macos, photo

In my app I want the user to either be able to click a button browse for a file or drag and drop it into the application and have it open the image. How can I do this? Which method would be easiest or do you recommend?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> In my app I want the user to either be able to click a button browse for a file

use NSOpenPanel, and specify the allowed types

> or drag and drop it into the application and have it open the image. How can I do this? Which method would be easiest or do you recommend?

subclass NSDocument, and associate the document type with the image mime-type; this association is made in your app's plist resource.

unless you have special needs, you can use CGImage and/or NSImage apis to open the image.